# Compiling Castle Microkernel and Windsor for Silverlight 2.0

Tags: silverlight, castle-windsor, silverlight-2.0

I am having trouble compiling Castle Microkernel and Windsor for Silverlight 2.0. I am working with the current build on the trunk (5837).

I can build the InversionOfControl-vs2008-SL.sln solution fine and this generates Core-Silverlight.dll no problems, but will only build the Microkernel and Windsor assemblies for .net and not for Silverlight.

I know this is still work in progress but I can't find a definitive answer as to whether this is possible yet, and if so, what I am doing wrong.

Comment: please post this on the google users group (http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users)

Comment: Done:
http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users/browse_thread/thread/9f067b9a2756f050#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windsor 2.1.1 now includes Silverlight 3 binaries.